# Memory consumption increases as I reinstall application

Tags: java, out-of-memory, websphere

I have EAR application which successfully works on my `WAS 8.5.5.5` installed on my Windows 7 PC. To install new version of app I use `maven-antrun-plugin` which simply copies the new built to `monitoredDeployableApps` folder of the server. After that old app version is being uninstalled and new one successfully installed.

But! When I look at my Task Manager I notice that memory consumption of java process (server) has been increased on ~150-200 mb. And every next update does the same until eventually app falls with `OutOfMemoryError`.

Server's `Xmx` is set to 1024mb, but memory consumption reaches ~2gb when it dies.

I also tried to analyze verbose gc log with http://gceasy.io It told me that `GC Interval avg time` is `4 sec 771 ms`. so I can conclude that GC starts often, but doesn't help anyway.

And the question is - why does memory consumption rise and never go down each time I reinstall my app ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using any fixpacks from the last 2 years?

Comment: just updated to 8.5.5.11, same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory growth on application restart is one of the hallmarks of a class loader leak - if some code outside your application is holding a reference to application classes, that prevents the entire application's class loader from being garbage collected (because all classes reference their class loaders).  150MB is awfully big for that, but there could be other stuff getting held onto as well.

If your app is creating its own threads, those are a huge source of these issues, through both references to app classes or through the thread holding the class loader as its thread context class loader.  Make sure you're cleaning up any threads that your application creates when the app is stopped.  It also could be a bug in a WebSphere component (something failing to clean up after itself) or an issue in your app or a third-party library (perhaps setting some reference at the JVM level).

WebSphere 8.5 has some function to check for that specific type of leak, as documented in this Knowledge Center article: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ttrb_configmemleak.html